# Convert Azure SQL to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'm a fairly new developer working on a database for a university research project. I created the database in Microsoft Access then used the SSMA Access to SQL migration tool to export it to Azure SQL. I'm now building a Ruby on Rails implementation of the databases front end on a Debian VPS and would like to migrate the Azure SQL database to MySQL for testing purposes with a view to eventually converting all of the database front ends to connect to the MySQL database.

I've been able to find plenty of articles discussing moving MySQL to Azure SQL but very little which details the process in reverse. Any and all help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: If your application is going to be hosted in Azure, why would you want a local database(mysql) running instead of having a cloud database(AzureSQL) running that your system can scale too? If your working in Azure I would recommend checking our C#'s database front end. Its quite easy with Azure.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear in my question. My VPS is hosted by Linode rather than Azure - hence the desire to convert. Given the requirements of the project Azure's pricing doesn't scale that well. I should also add I'm an archaeologist first and foremost - the whole developer aspect is more something I've picked up by trial and error (plus a few extremely patient friends).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql allows you to import full database dumps (table definitions and content) as long as they are in sql format, in a text file.

As long as you manage to generate a dump of your database as a text file of sql statements you should be ok.

The only thing is azure may not give you the chance to generate that dump.
But you'll probably have third party tools that will allow you to.

If not, since you initially built you database in access you will for certain find free tools to do a access to mysql migrations. (a quick google search shows me [bullzip](http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php) and [mdbtools](http://mdbtools.sourceforge.net/) as two free tools that do just that.)

Once you have your sql dump file just import it into mysql from the command line or using the source command in the mysql client.

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't it be better to write code that is database agnostic. That is your code shouldn't care what database you are using

Comment: Originally the plan was to write the RoR front end to connect to the Azure SQL database using TinyTDS and a few other tools. As this RoR app will be hosted on a VPS which is capable of running a MySQL database locally I wanted to do this conversion so I can skip having my (Linode) VPS have to pull the data from a different server. I'm wanting to switch to a fully VPS hosted solution to save on costs - it's an archaeological database which is likely to only have a small number of users and the Azure pricing plan to host all the services (including an SSL secured website) doesn't scale well.